# How to filter category collection using storefilter?

Tags: php, magento, collections, filter, categories

I have one admin module and I want to get category collection storewise in that module so how can we filter collection using storefilter? addstorefilter is not working for category collection .

Comment: my solution, code example....

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/19284088/1266559][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19284088/1266559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have add below code and its working for me

```
$storecategoryid = Mage::app()->getStore($storeid)->getRootCategoryId();
```

from this code i get  store root categoryid.

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('is_active',array('eq' => 1))->load();
```

from this i get whole category collection

```
foreach($category as $cat)
{
  if($cat->getData('level')==2 && $cat->getData('parent_id')==$storecategoryid)
  { 
     echo 'my code';
  }
}
```

This way I get store category.

Comment: use `->addIsActiveFilter()` and `addPathsFilter('/' . $storecategoryid . '/')`.

Comment: yes, but your question was not clear. You have wanted to filter by root category not by store

Comment: yes i want it to filter by store, i have not find any solution to filter by store so i have put this kind of logic because my root category is different for different store and putting this logic solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Use setStore or setStoreId methods:

```
$collection = Mage:getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');

// or $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();

$collection->setStoreId($myStoreId)
   ->load();
```

**UPDATE:**
There is a simple script to check this:

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::app('admin');

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->setStoreId(2)
    ->load();

echo $collection->count(), "\n";
foreach ($collection as $item) {
   echo $item->getName(), "\n";
}
```

If you have 3 store views there will 3 storeIds. There are 0 - for admin store, 1 - for default store and 2 (or other value) for another store. I have just checked this and it works.

Comment: @mufaddal which version of Magento?

Answer (score 1):

```
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
$categories->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/{$rootCategoryId}/%"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Props going to [@xpoback](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2000848/xpoback) for the correct answer. I wanted to reiterate the answer as there are a few answers that are somewhat correct and some that are not.

Short answer, use this:

```
$rootId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getResourceCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/{$rootId}/%"))
        ->addIsActiveFilter();
```

For all who want to know the issues with other answers read on.

First off, the [@Muffadal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1326539/mufaddal)'s answer is functional, but is extremely slow in terms of performance. You want to keep the data querying up to mySQL and not use php looping over a big collection (provided you have more than a few categories in your store).

The comment under that answer to use `addPathsFilter('/' . $storecategoryid . '/')` is also correct, but will be slower than using the LIKE operator in this case (see [article](https://thingsilearn.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/mysql-query-speed-regexp-vs-like/))

[@Serjio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1445507/serjio)'s method will not work in terms of distinguishing between different categories. What it will do is pull store specific translations. Example Store 1 has named the category *Rings*, Store 2 has named the same category *My Rings*. 
If we make the call from store 2 using his code, it will pull all categories no matter the Root, but will pull the Store 2's naming convention - *My Rings*

Answer (score 0):

**In Magento 1.9**

```
$storeId=2;
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();


            $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->getCollection()
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/{$rootCategoryId}/%"))
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

                foreach($categories as $categorie)
                {
                    $catid=$cat->getId();                   
                    $catname=$categorie->getName();
                    $catp=catp$categorie->getParent_id();
                }
```